# dateFormatter is returning January as the month when the data in the json array is February

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert the date stored in my json array as yyyy-mm-dd (i.e. 2013-02-14) to Day, date month year (i.e. Thu 14 Feb 2013) and for some reason it is converting the month to January, can anyone tell me why please? Thank you.

```
NSString *endDate = [info objectForKey:@"EndDate"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
NSDate *edate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE d MMM yyyy"];
NSString *convertedEndDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:edate];
```

Comment: Maybe january is 0, february is 1,... (Don't know excactly as i don't develop for iOS.)

Comment: Hi Johannes, not sure that's the answer, what I should have said is that if I use dd/mm/yyyy as my second dateformatter it works so I'm wondered if it's the EEE that's throwing it off?

Comment: @JohannesMittendorfer no, January is 1, February is 2, etc. though this has nothing to do with the issue. Using `mm` instead of `MM` is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for the month is "MM", not "mm" (which is for minutes):

```
NSString *endDate = @"2013-02-14";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *edate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE d MMM yyyy"];
NSString *convertedEndDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:edate];
NSLog(@"%@", convertedEndDate);
```

*Output:*

```
Thu 14 Feb 2013
```